# Automatic update linked Smart object

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, actionscript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I apologize in advance if my English is not good, hi I found one of your posts regarding automatic update linked smart objects, but it doesn't work in the case I'm facing, can you help me I'm making a mockup for a jersey design based on smart objects and designs on Inside I use a linked smart object to retrieve the existing source file but it can't run when using the script you have created...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Gmail is the other tab.